# Update document field value depending ils value on single button click

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

Foreach of my "categories" collection document's (5), i'm displaying a button. And i would like when I click on my button it change the value of my document "active" field to "yes" or "no" depending of the old value.

This is what I tried :

```
    db.collection("categories").orderBy("id", "asc").onSnapshot(snapshot =>
    {
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges();

        changes.forEach(change =>
        {
            if (change.type == "added" || change.type == "removed")
            {
                renderNavItems(change.doc);
                renderTab(change.doc);
                renderButtons(change.doc);
            }
            else if(change.type == "modified")
            {
                buttonFc(change.doc);
            }
         })
     });
```

**RenderButtons() Function :** (Only one time)

```
var buttons;
var button;
var buttonDiv;


function renderButtons(doc)
{
    button = document.createElement("button");
    buttonDiv = document.createElement("div");

    buttonDiv.setAttribute("class","btnDiv"+doc.data().id);

        if (doc.data().active == "yes")
        {
            button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-success btn-sm btnView");
            button.textContent= "Slide activée";
        }
        else if (doc.data().active == "no")
        {
            button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-danger btn-sm btnView");
            button.textContent= "Slide desactivée";
        }

    buttonDiv.appendChild(button);

    var tab = document.querySelector("#"+doc.data().name);
    tab.appendChild(buttonDiv);

    buttonFc(doc);
}
```

**buttonFc() function :** (Each time, the value of my field change)

```
function buttonFc(doc)
{
    DocRef = db.collection("categories").doc(doc.id);

    if (doc.data().active == "yes")
    {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => 
        {
            console.log("YES TO NO");
            DocRef.update({
                "active": "no"
        })
    });

}
else if (doc.data().active == "no")
{

    button.addEventListener('click', () => 
    {
        console.log("NO TO YES");
        DocRef.update({
            "active": "yes"
            })
    });
}
```

But, when I click on a button, my functions loops and each time loop is bigger.

When I click 5 time :

[image: Exemple]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttonFc() function adds a new eventlistener for each time it is called, so you end up with multiple eventlisteners on the same button. This explains why the loop gets 'bigger' each time.
Make sure you add eventlisteners only once.